# Trying to get property of non-object error PHP curl

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Im trying to use an api to get a fruit information.

```
$fruitStirng = 'apple';

$url = "https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/".$fruitStirng;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
    
$main = json_decode($res);
```

Result should be something like this :

```
{ "genus": "Malus", "name": "Apple", "id": 6, "family": "Rosaceae", "order": "Rosales", "nutritions": { "carbohydrates": 11.4, "protein": 0.3, "fat": 0.4, "calories": 52, "sugar": 10.3 } }
```

but for example when im trying echo `genus` like this :

```
$genus = $main->genus;
echo $genus
```

I get `Trying to get property 'genus' of non-object` error !

I also used foreach but got an error too

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: Is `$res` not equal to `false`? Try `var_dump($res);`

Comment: In case it's `false`, use `if (curl_errno($ch)) { $error_msg = curl_error($ch);}` to echo's the error. Possible error could be `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificatebool(false)` or something related.

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky ops its false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since API returning the JSON uses HTTPS, you must configure cURL SSL option (CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER). Here's a working code:

```
<?php
$fruitString = 'apple';

$url = "https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/".$fruitString;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);

$main = json_decode($res);

$genus = $main->genus;
echo $genus; // Malus
```